# Concatenating Values to Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a Pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(['Apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'apple'], columns=['A'])


        A
0   Apple
1  orange
2    pear
3   apple
```

Let's say I have this:

```
stuff = 'hello'
```

Is there a way to concatenate the values from the variable (`stuff` in this case) to all the values in the 1st column?

Results of what I would like:

```
        A
0   Apple - hello
1  orange - hello
2    pear - hello
3   apple - hello
```

**Edit #1:**

The solutions below work, but if your dataframe has more than 1 column, you need to specify that column.

i.e. use `df3.b = df3.b + ' whatever'` and NOT `df3 = df3.b + ' whatever'`

Comment: df2.A+=' - hello'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
df2[['A']] + ' - hello'
```

OR

```
stuff = hello
df2[['A']] + ' - ' + stuff
```

Or as @piRSquared suggest using the [f-string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) Python 3.6+ syntax:

```
df2 + f" - {stuff}"
```

Output:

```
                A
0   Apple - hello
1  orange - hello
2    pear - hello
3   apple - hello
```

Comment: I couldn't bring myself to make my own answer. `df2 + f" - {stuff}"`

Comment: Ah.. yes,  f-string syntax.

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
df2.A + '-hello'
```

Comment: This looks like the same concept as @ScottBoston but 2 minutes later.

Comment: the answer wasn't posted when I started